# Using one equals sign in an if statement

Tags: php

In a PHP `if` statement, when I am comparing a variable I would need to use two `==` signs. For example,

```
if($foo == 'bar'){
    //Run code
}
```

But if I were to use one equals sign like this:

```
if($foo = 'bar'){
    //Run code
}
```

This would actually set the `$foo` variable.

Why would you ever need to set a variable like this inside an `if` statement? I can't think of one instance where this would be useful, and many programmers I've spoken to feel the same way.

Is there a reason why PHP allows you to set a variable this way?

Comment: "Is there a reason why PHP allows you to set a variable this way?" It is a result of PHP's loose typing. Personally I avoid this kind of thing as it can be done in error resulting in hard to spot bugs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP, like also C, allows to write any expression into an if-condition.

This can be an expression like:

```
if(!$db=new database()) die("NO DATABASE CONNECTION");
```

But it has rather the background that the expression `$a="abc"` is evaluated a different way:

1. Set the value of $a to abc
2. Rest of the expression is: `if($a)`
3. $a is != 0, so it is true **MOST IMPORTANT**
4. Expression is true, go into if-case

So the expression is evaluated to if(true) because the priority table of
operators make the expression succeed. It is not a mistake of PHP, it is 
rather the definition of TRUE/FALSE and how things get evaluated.

This can also be used in loops like shown in another answer for the loop expression with `$db->fetch()`

Answer (score 7):

Testing the result of a function that returns an error:

```
if (($err = some_function())) {
    echo "Error: " . $err;
}
```

Comment: Note one thing though, heed the manual in these cases when it says "a function may return false or NULL`. Since NULL is implicitly cast to false, you may need to use `if (($err = some_function()) !== NULL)` to get the behaviour you want.

Answer (score 4):

One of the most common usecases is to make sure something exists (or is truthy), and then use it inside the block, for example:

```
while ($row = $dbConnection->fetch()) { //Make sure that $dbConnection->fetch() is not false or NULL...
    //You can use $row here!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For simplifying, for example.

```
if ($var instanceof MyClass && $obj = $var->getResultObject()){
    /// do something
}
```

instead of

```
if ($var instanceof MyClass){
    $obj = $var->getResultObject()
    if ($obj){
       /// do something
    }
}
```